# Outgoing UDP connections on port 123 dropped by firewall

Tags: centos7, udp

I have the following entries in my firewall log (LOGDROP). Are they to do with internet time synchronization? Does it matter if they are dropped? Is it something more sinister? I've researched the destination URLs (129.70.132.32 and 78.46.93.106) but am none the wiser: they don't seem to give much away.

```
Jul 18 15:01:28 idea-software kernel: IPTables Packet Dropped: IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=w.x.y.x DST=129.70.132.32 LEN=76 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=123 DPT=123 LEN=56
Jul 18 15:01:39 idea-software kernel: IPTables Packet Dropped: IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=w.x.y.x DST=78.46.93.106 LEN=76 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=123 DPT=123 LEN=56
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely `NTP` services. Check if your ntp daemon is running, disable it (if possible) for awhile and see if the firewall log messages go away. Just make sure your clock drift isn't adversely affected while `ntpd` is down. You could also enable outbound `NTP` for only specific servers by [altering](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sect-Date_and_Time_Configuration-Command_Line_Configuration-Network_Time_Protocol.html) your `ntpd` config instead of the 'global' defaults.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - it does seem to be NTP. I'm sure stopping the daemon would remove the messages but I want NTP to work!
I am trying a firewall update: iptables -I OUTPUT 12  -p udp --dport 123 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT......

Comment: Yes, that should work fine as long as there is no rule before #12 which may inadvertently block your newly added rule.  It's been a couple days since you applied that rule; try `iptables --line-numbers -nvL OUTPUT` and see if the packet counters have gone up to verify (`pkts` column in the output).